# Rails/HTML mount three buttons alongside

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I've got 3 buttons that are next to each other and in my Macbook 13'' everything looks like it should:

[image: Macbook13'']

But it turns out on a Zenbook 14 (which has a bigger screen?!) things get weird:

[image: Zenbook14]

I'm using bootstrap, how to prevent such situation? Code below:

```
Status: <%= UserAuthorization.statuses[authorization.status].upcase %>
</br>
<% unless authorization.approved? %>
  <button class="modal-trigger btn btn-bh btn-xs btn-lng",
          data-toggle="modal",
          data-target="#confirm-caregiver-approve",
          data-modal-confirm-url="<%= approve_caregiver_authorization_path(authorization, registrant_page: true) %>">
          APPROVE
  </button>
<% end %>
<% unless authorization.declined? %>
  <button class="modal-trigger btn btn-bh btn-xs btn-lng",
          data-toggle="modal",
          data-target="#confirm-caregiver-decline",
          data-modal-confirm-url="<%= decline_caregiver_authorization_path(authorization, registrant_page: true) %>">
          DECLINE
  </button>
<% end %>
<% if authorization.pending? %>
  <button class="modal-trigger btn btn-bh btn-xs btn-lng",
          data-toggle="modal",
          data-target="#confirm-caregiver-in_review",
          data-modal-confirm-url="<%= in_review_caregiver_authorization_path(authorization, registrant_page: true) %>">
          IN REVIEW
  </button>
<% end %>
```

**[Edit]**

This file is a partial so the file that renders it looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= render partial: 'user_authorizations/user_authorization_review',
               locals: { authorization: registrant.user_authorizations.last } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I'm trying to add grid like below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      button here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      button here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      button here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's even worst:

[image: After grid]

Comment: Are you using CSS framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: @brcebn Yes, I'm using Bootstrap here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using `Bootstrap` I would suggest you to use the [Grid layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/) and wrap your buttons into a `row`.

Here is something that might match:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      button here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      button here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      button here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: I've updated my answer. Play with `offset` and size of the column. 

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck here - https://ibb.co/MRbrCTB